# Objective C incompatible

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to Objective C, and am getting a little confused by the behavior of my code.

`.m` file:

```
@interface MEDTNetworkAuthentication()

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *certificate;

@implementation MEDTNetworkAuthentication

-(void)setCertificate:(NSData*) certificateData 
{
    self.certificate=[self getCarelinkCertificateUsingData:certificateData];
    return;
}

@end
```

`.h` file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol NetworkAuthenticationDelegate;

@interface MEDTNetworkAuthentication : NSObject<NSURLSessionDelegate>

-(void)authenticate:(NSData*) certificateData andAuthData:(NSString*) authorization andURLSession:(NSURLSession*) careLinkAuthenticationSession;
-(void)setCertificate:(NSData*) certificateData;

@end
```

Now, the `authenticate` was existing functionality in the code before. Previously, I changed put `return;` after setting `self.certificate`, and it functions as expected. But since I want that previous functionality and don't want to get rid of it all, I wanted to create a new function (`setCertificate`). But when I add that function to the `.h` and `.m` files, now BOTH lines setting `self.certertificate` are giving me an error saying `Assigning to 'NSData *__strong' from incompatible type 'NSString *'`. When I delete the line for `setCertificate` from the `.h` file, the error goes away, but I can't access that function outside the m file now (obviously). What's going on?

Comment: You left out the the data type of your `cert` property. Add that to your question.

Comment: FYI - when you want help with code that is giving you problems, please copy and paste the real, exact code into your question. You've trimmed off too much in your question.

Comment: Updated - sorry about that

Comment: You are returning NSData instead of NSString.

Comment: How is it returning NSData?

Comment: Post your actual code don't trim it

Comment: Is your real code actually using `self.cert = ...` or is it really using `self.certificate = ...`? Again, post REAL code.

Comment: Voting to close this question as it stands because it is unclear, has code but not a MVCE

Comment: I'm trying to update it, but it'd probably be easier to close and ask another one I guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that you've posted real code with real property names and real method names, the problem is obvious.

As I guessed, your property is named `certificate`, not `cert`. So your `setCertificate:` method is hiding the setter method for your `certificate` property.

Since the `certificate` property is of type `NSString` and your `setCertificate:` method takes a parameter of type `NSData`, you have a conflict.

The proper solution is to renamed your `setCertificate:` method so it doesn't conflict with your property.

Maybe change it to `setCertificateData:`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because from this function

```
-(NSString *)getCert:(NSData *)certData
{
    //do something
}
```

you are returning a `NSString` and `self.cert` is a variable of type `NSData` which expect `NSData` not `NSString`

Answer (score 0):

Property `cert` seems to be of type NSString, and you are passing an NSData instance to it. Perhaps try using NSString's `initWithData:encoding:`